# FAT12 - reading first cluster number of file from root directory

Tags: operating-system, fat

In the root directory of FAT12, bytes 26-27 represent the number of the first cluster of the file. However, cluster numbers in FAT12 are 12 bits long. So what part of that 2 byte entry in the root directory contains the actual 12 bit cluster number ? Is there any conversion that needs to be performed on reading those 2 bytes to get the cluster ? I have looked around over the Internet, but cant find a proper explanation for this.

Comment: Are you sure it is clusters we are talking about? IIRC in FAT12/FAT16 that number is a *sector* number. In FAT32 it is a cluster number.

Comment: Well it would depend on the sectors per cluster, but in a generic sense I am talking about cluster numbers. For example, I am working with a floppy image as the boot disk and for that, sectors per cluster = 1 so cluster => sector.

Answer (score 1):

The lowest 12 bits, i.e. you do an `& 0x0FFF` in your code. But on the other hand, the full 16 bits are used – the other 4 bits are just filled with 0, so the number is a valid word (16-bit integer).